# Oracle : replace string of options based on data set - is this possible?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have column in table looking like this:

```
PATTERN
{([option1]+[option2])*([option3]+[option4])}
{([option1]+[option2])*([option3]+[option4])*([option6]+[option7])}
{[option1]+[option6]}
{([option1]+[option2])*([option8]+[option9])}
{([option1]+[option2])*[option4]}
{[option10]}
```

Every option has a number of value.
There is a table - let's call it `option_set` and records look like

```
OPTION      VALUE
option1     3653265
option2     26452
option3     73552
option3     100
option4     1235
option5     42565
option6     2330
option7     544
option9     2150
```

I want to replace option name to number in 1st table, if exists of course, if not exists then =0.
I have done this in PLSQL (get the pattern, go through every option, and if exists - regexp_replace),
but I am wondering if this could be done in SQL??
My goal is to replace values for all patterns for current OPTION_SET and get only records, where all equations would be greater than 0. Of course - I couldn't run this equation in SQL, so I think of something like

```
for rec in
(
  SELECT...
)
loop
  execute immediate '...';
  if above_equation > 0 then ..
end loop;
```

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Are that `{` and `}` surrond the entire expression and not present in the expression itself?

Comment: Yes, these are { and }, and during the process they are cutted out. If You have some idea that includes no brackets, feel free to delete them

Comment: Your "options" table has option3 twice. That makes no sense.

Comment: My mistake. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a loop-like query in SQL with the recursive CTE, replacing new token on each iteration, so this will let you to replace all the tokens.
The only way I know to execute a dynamic query inside SQL statement in Oracle is [`DBMS_XMLGEN`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_xmlgen.htm#ARPLS374) package, so you can evaluate the expression and filter by the result value without PL/SQL. But all this is viable for low cardinality tables with patterns and options.

Here's the code:

> ```
> with a as (
>   select 1 as id, '{([option1]+[option2])*([option3]+[option4])}' as pattern from dual union all
>   select 2 as id, '{([option1]+[option2])*([option3]+[option4])*([option6]+[option7])}' as pattern from dual union all
>   select 3 as id, '{[option1]+[option6]}' as pattern from dual union all
>   select 4 as id, '{([option1]+[option2])*([option8]+[option9])}' as pattern from dual union all
>   select 5 as id, '{([option1]+[option2])*[option4]}' as pattern from dual union all
>   select 6 as id, '{[option10]}]' as pattern from dual
> )
> , opt as (
>   select 'option1' as opt, 3653265 as val from dual union all
>   select 'option2' as opt, 26452 as val from dual union all
>   select 'option3' as opt, 73552 as val from dual union all
>   select 'option3' as opt, 100 as val from dual union all
>   select 'option4' as opt, 1235 as val from dual union all
>   select 'option5' as opt, 42565 as val from dual union all
>   select 'option6' as opt, 2330 as val from dual union all
>   select 'option7' as opt, 544 as val from dual union all
>   select 'option9' as opt, 2150 as val from dual
> )
> , opt_ordered as (
>   /*Order options to iterate over*/
>   select opt.*, row_number() over(order by 1) as rn
>   from opt
> )
> , rec (id, pattern, repl_pattern, lvl) as (
>   select
>     id,
>     pattern,
>     pattern as repl_pattern,
>     0 as lvl
>   from a
>   
>   union all
>   
>   select
>     r.id,
>     r.pattern,
>     /*Replace each part at new step*/
>     replace(r.repl_pattern, '[' || o.opt || ']', o.val),
>     r.lvl + 1
>   from rec r
>     join opt_ordered o
>       on r.lvl + 1 = o.rn
> )
> , out_prepared as (
>   select
>     rec.*,
>     case
>       when instr(repl_pattern, '[') = 0
>       /*When there's no more not parsed expressions, then we can try to evaluate them*/
>       then dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(
>         'select ' || replace(replace(repl_pattern, '{', ''), '}', '')
>         || ' as v from dual'
>       )
>       /*Otherwise SQL statement will fail*/
>     end as parsed_expr
>   from rec
>   /*Retrieve the last step*/
>   where lvl = (select max(rn) from opt_ordered)
> )
> select
>   id,
>   pattern,
>   repl_pattern,
>   extractvalue(parsed_expr, '/ROWSET/ROW/V') as calculated_value
> from out_prepared o
> where extractvalue(parsed_expr, '/ROWSET/ROW/V') > 0
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | PATTERN                                                             | REPL_PATTERN                              | CALCULATED_VALUE
> -: | :------------------------------------------------------------------ | :---------------------------------------- | :---------------
>  1 | {([option1]+[option2])*([option3]+[option4])}                       | {(3653265+26452)*(73552+1235)}            | 275194995279    
>  2 | {([option1]+[option2])*([option3]+[option4])*([option6]+[option7])} | {(3653265+26452)*(73552+1235)*(2330+544)} | 790910416431846 
>  3 | {[option1]+[option6]}                                               | {3653265+2330}                            | 3655595         
>  5 | {([option1]+[option2])*[option4]}                                   | {(3653265+26452)*1235}                    | 4544450495
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ddf2c8fc0ff5f8b2ea05f0cf0c0e4877)*

Comment: Great! Perfect! One question - could You explain to me recursive query? How this is working or mayby You know some good tutorial?

Comment: @q4za4 A brief description is present right [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#BCEJGIBG). And at the end of that article you can find some examples. In short: there's an **anchor member**, that creates the base data, from which recursion starts, and **recursive member**, which uses the same `with` name in `from` or `join` clauses to increment the recursion step. At each step the data, produced by recursive member, is added to the existing data of that `with` subquery. Recursion stops when there's no new data at the new step.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this. There's a lot to unpack, so hang on tight.

I include the test data in the `with` clause. Of course, you won't need that; simply remove the two "tables" and use your actual table and column names in the query.

From Oracle 12.1 on, we can define PL/SQL functions directly in the `with` clause, right at the top; if we do so, the query must be terminated with a slash (/) instead of the usual semicolon (;). If your version is earlier than 12.1, you can define the function separately. The function I use takes an "arithmetic expression" (a string representing a compound arithmetic operation) and returns its value as a number. It uses native dynamic SQL (the "execute immediate" statement), which will cause the query to be relatively slow, as a different cursor is parsed for each row. If speed becomes an issue, this can be changed, to use a bind variable (so that the cursor is parsed only once).

The recursive query in the `with` clause replaces each placeholder with the corresponding value for the "options" table. I use 0 either if a "placeholder" doesn't have a corresponding option in the table, or if it does but the corresponding value is `null`. (Note that your sample data shows `option3` twice; that makes no sense, and I removed one occurrence from my sample data.)

Instead of replacing one placeholder at a time, I took the opposite approach; assuming the patterns may be long, but the number of "options" is small, this should be more efficient. Namely: at each step, I replace ALL occurrences of `'[optionN]'` (for a given `N`) in a single pass. Outside the recursive query, I replace all the placeholders for "non-existent" options with 0.

Note that recursive `with` clause requires Oracle 11.2. If your version is even earlier than that (although it shouldn't be), there are other ways; you would likely need to do that in PL/SQL also.

So, here it is - a single `SELECT` query for the whole thing:

```
with
  function expr_eval(pattern varchar2) return number as
    x number;
  begin
    execute immediate 'select ' || pattern || ' from dual' into x;
    return x;
  end;
  p (id, pattern) as (
    select 1, '{([option1]+[option2])*([option3]+[option4])}'                       from dual union all
    select 2, '{([option1]+[option2])*([option3]+[option4])*([option6]+[option7])}' from dual union all
    select 3, '{[option1]+[option6]}'                                               from dual union all
    select 4, '{([option1]+[option2])*([option8]+[option9])}'                       from dual union all
    select 5, '{([option1]+[option2])*[option4]}'                                   from dual union all
    select 6, '{[option10]}'                                                        from dual union all
    select 7, '{[option2]/([option3]+[option8])-(300-[option2])/(0.1 *[option3])}'  from dual
  )
, o (opt, val) as (
    select 'option1', 3653265 from dual union all
    select 'option2',   26452 from dual union all
    select 'option3',     100 from dual union all
    select 'option4',    1235 from dual union all
    select 'option5',   42565 from dual union all
    select 'option6',    2330 from dual union all
    select 'option7',     544 from dual union all
    select 'option9',    2150 from dual
  )
, n (opt, val, rn, ct) as (
    select opt, val, rownum, count(*) over ()
    from   o
  )
, r (id, pattern, rn, ct) as (
    select id, substr(pattern, 2, length(pattern) - 2), 1, null
      from p
    union all
    select r.id, replace(r.pattern, '[' || n.opt || ']', nvl(to_char(n.val), 0)),
           r.rn + 1, n.ct
      from r join n on r.rn = n.rn
  )
, ae (id, pattern) as (
    select id, regexp_replace(pattern, '\[[^]]*]', '0')
    from   r
    where  rn = ct + 1
  ) 
select id, expr_eval(pattern) as result 
from   ae
order  by id
/
```

Output:

```
  ID          RESULT
---- ---------------
   1      4912422195
   2  14118301388430
   3         3655595
   4      7911391550
   5      4544450495
   6               0
   7         2879.72
```

Comment: Great! Perfect! One question - could You explain to me recursive query? How this is working or mayby You know some good tutorial?

Comment: @q4za4 - To see what it does, add `select * from r` right after the definition of `r` (and comment out the rest of the query, beginning from `ae`). That will show you what the recursive query does. Then look at the definition of `ae` to see what we actually want from `r`. Other than that, you will need to read about recursive queries - they can't be explained just in a short comment here.